# generating LaTeX tabular code during compilation

Tags: tables, compiling, arrays

I use LaTeX for scientific reporting in brain imaging (fMRI). I have a `tabular` array in LaTeX, that contains quite a lot of rows and columns, which both are brain regions and in the each intersecting cell there is some data about their connections.

The content of this `tabular` array is defined separately in another .tex file that is loaded using `\input` command. In this another .tex file the content of each cell of the `tabular` array is defined separately using hundreds of `\newcommand` commands. In `tabular` array there is no other content except these `\newcommand` commands. `tabular` array is inside `\begin{spreadtab}` to permit some basic calculations of cells values (although this is not a requirement). Everything works fine so far.

So, the `\newcommand` definitions look like this:

```
\newcommand{\origREGIONONEdestREGIONONE}{ NA } % NA for cells on the diagonal.
\newcommand{\origREGIONONEdestREGIONTWO}{ - } % this is the default case.
```

...

```
\newcommand{\origREGINOTWOdestREGIONTWO}{ NA }
\newcommand{\origREGIONTWOdestREGIONONE}{ \ref{Spielberg1981} }
\newcommand{\origREGIONTWOdestREGIONTHREE}{ bilateral \ref{Cameron1989} }
```

...

There is a specific `\newcommand` definition for all column x row intersections.

The `tabular` array code looks like this (a 3x3 example but in reality it is bigger than 20x20):

```
\tiny
\begin{table}
    \scalebox{0.6}{
        \begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{*{3}{c}}}
            \hline
            \to/from :={} & REGIONONE :={} & REGIONTWO :={} & REGIONTHREE :={} \\
            \hline
            to REGIONONE :={} & \origREGIONONEdestREGIONONE :={} & \origREGIONTWOdestREGIONONE :={} &\origREGIONTHREEdestREGIONONE :={} \\
            to REGIONTWO :={} & \origREGIONONEdestREGIONTWO :={} & \origREGIONTWOdestREGIONTWO :={} &\origREGIONTHREEdestREGIONTWO :={} \\
            to REGIONTHREE :={} & \origREGIONONEdestREGIONTHREE :={} & \origREGIONTWOdestREGIONTHREE :={} &\origREGIONTHREEdestREGIONTHREE :={} \\
            \hline
        \end{spreadtab}
    } % end scalebox
    \caption{A table of connections between brain regions 1, 2 & 3}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \cite{Spielberg1981}\label{Spielberg1981}
        \item \cite{Cameron1989}\label{Cameron1989}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{table}
\normalsize
```

Now what I want is to be able to generate a similar `tabular` definition dynamically according to a list or an array of strings (or using any possible datatype):

in MATLAB syntax it would be: `ListOfBrainRegions = { 'BRAINREGIONABC', 'BRAINREGIONDEF', 'BRAINREGIONXYZ' }`

In Python syntax: `ListOfBrainRegions = [ 'BRAINREGIONABC', 'BRAINREGIONDEF', 'BRAINREGIONXYZ' ]`

The list or array would be translated into a code like this inside `spreadtab` (or without `spreadtab` if it causes some problems):

```
            \hline
            \to/from :={} & REGIONABC :={} & REGIONDEF :={} & REGIONXYZ :={} \\
            \hline
            to REGIONABC :={} & \origREGIONABCdestREGIONABC :={} & \origREGIONDEFdestREGIONABC :={} &\origREGIONXYZdestREGIONABC :={} \\
            to REGIONDEF :={} & \origREGIONABCdestREGIONDEF :={} & \origREGIONDEFdestREGIONDEF :={} &\origREGIONXYZdestREGIONDEF :={} \\
            to REGIONXYZ :={} & \origREGIONABCdestREGIONXYZ :={} & \origREGIONDEFdestREGIONXYZ :={} &\origREGIONXYZdestREGIONXYZ :={} \\
            \hline
```

So, how should I define `ListOfBrainRegions` in LaTeX? And then how can I generate LaTeX code during compiling of a .tex file? If I was to program this in some other programming language, for example in MATLAB, Common Lisp or awk the task (generating program code) would not be difficult at all. It seems that LaTeX does not have built-in arrays, `if` ... `elseif` ... `else` commands nor `for` or `while` loops, although some packages provide some added functionality. So, how this could be implemented? Or, which LaTeX commands, packages and/or extra tools should I use for this task?

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: If you feel that TeX lacks a real programming language or programming using the TeX constructs feels fussy, you might be interested in [LuaTeX](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Main_Page).

Comment: @Marco LuaTeX might be an interesting option. But is there a way for a generic transformation (a regular expression or something) to convert **any** LaTeX file into a valid LuaTeX file? What I find most difficult in LaTeX, in addition to the lack of common programming constructs, is getting the packages work together (I currently have 19).

Comment: There is not much to convert, LuaTeX is only the backend engine. Since LuaTeX is -more or less- a superset of pdfTeX, you can keep your existing files and packages. The most noticeable difference is the font handling and the encoding; and, of course, the embedded scripting language. It's probably a few lines of change in the preamble to switch from pdfTeX to LuaTeX. However, it changes nothing regarding the package mess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the LaTeX format does have loops `\@tfor` etc, but in tables TeX is in a bit of a delicate state so here I have just use plain expansion.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\def\listheadings{%
\expandafter\xlistheadings\regionlist,\relax,}

\def\xlistheadings#1,{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\expandafter\\%
\else
&\textbf{#1}%
\expandafter\xlistheadings
\fi}

\def\listbody{%
\expandafter\xlistbody\regionlist,\relax,}

\def\xlistbody#1,{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\else
\textbf{#1}%
\gdef\thisrow{#1}%
\expandafter\xlistdata\regionlist,\relax,%
\expandafter\xlistbody
\fi}


\def\xlistdata#1,{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\expandafter\\%
\else
&\csname origREGION\thisrow destREGION#1\endcsname
\expandafter\xlistdata
\fi}


\def\preamble{\expandafter\xpreamble\regionlist,\relax,}
\def\xpreamble#1,{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\else
c|%
\expandafter\xpreamble
\fi}

\def\tablestart{%
\edef\temp{\noexpand\begin{tabular}{|c|\preamble}}%
\temp}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\regionlist{ONE,TWO,THREE}

\def\origREGIONONEdestREGIONONE{1/1}
\def\origREGIONONEdestREGIONTWO{1/2}
\def\origREGIONONEdestREGIONTHREE{1/3}

\def\origREGIONTWOdestREGIONONE{2/1}
\def\origREGIONTWOdestREGIONTWO{2/2}
\def\origREGIONTWOdestREGIONTHREE{2/3}

\def\origREGIONTHREEdestREGIONONE{3/1}
\def\origREGIONTHREEdestREGIONTWO{3/2}
\def\origREGIONTHREEdestREGIONTHREE{3/3}


\tablestart
\hline
\listheadings
\hline
\listbody
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is an excellent answer and helps me enormously. I have been searching and looking for a solution for months every now and then.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution with `expl3` which shows some nice features of the language:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\generatetable}{m}{\nrz_generate_table:n {#1}}

\seq_new:N \l_nrz_head_seq
\tl_new:N \l_nrz_preamble_tl
\tl_new:N \l_nrz_header_tl
\tl_new:N \l_nrz_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \nrz_generate_table:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_nrz_head_seq { , } { #1 }
  \nrz_generate_table_data:
  \nrz_output_table:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \nrz_generate_table_data:
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_nrz_preamble_tl { | c | }
  \tl_clear:N \l_nrz_header_tl
  \tl_clear:N \l_nrz_body_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_nrz_head_seq
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_nrz_preamble_tl { c | }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_nrz_header_tl { & \textbf{ ##1 } }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_nrz_body_tl { \textbf{ ##1 } } % first col
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_nrz_head_seq % other cols
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_nrz_body_tl { & \use:c { origREGION ##1 destREGION ####1 } }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_nrz_body_tl { \\ }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_nrz_header_tl { \\ }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \nrz_output_table:
 {
  \begin{tabular}{ \tl_use:N \l_nrz_preamble_tl }
  \hline
  \tl_use:N \l_nrz_header_tl
  \hline
  \tl_use:N \l_nrz_body_tl
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\origREGIONONEdestREGIONONE{1/1}
\def\origREGIONONEdestREGIONTWO{1/2}
\def\origREGIONONEdestREGIONTHREE{1/3}

\def\origREGIONTWOdestREGIONONE{2/1}
\def\origREGIONTWOdestREGIONTWO{2/2}
\def\origREGIONTWOdestREGIONTHREE{2/3}

\def\origREGIONTHREEdestREGIONONE{3/1}
\def\origREGIONTHREEdestREGIONTWO{3/2}
\def\origREGIONTHREEdestREGIONTHREE{3/3}

\generatetable{ONE,TWO,THREE}

\end{document}
```

The body of the table is built with a mapping function inside another mapping function, using the *same* sequence for the mapping!

First of all we build the sequence from the list passed as argument to `\generatetable`; then we proceed to use the sequence so obtained to build the table preamble (starting with `|c|` and adding `c|` at each step), the table header (adding `& <string>` at each step and a final `\\`) and the table body, one row at a time. Rows are built similarly, with an inner loop.

[image]