# How to add \hline to macro expansion?

Tags: macros, expansion

I want to add one `\hline` to the macro expansion of this code, that is minimally modified version of David Carlisle's answer to [Generating LaTeX tabular code during compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52472/generating-latex-tabular-code-during-compilation").

Compiling this with `latexmk -pdf main.tex` gives a nice tabular. I was able to add `\hline` to the macro expansion of the macro that generates most of the rows by adding `\def\hardline{\hline}` and `\expandafter\hardline` in `\def\xlistbody` in `g_orig_dest_tabular1_def.tex`. I was also able to add `\hline` in the beginning of the code by adding `\noexpand\hline` in `\def\tablestart` in the same file. But I was not able to find out how I could generate `\hline` between first and second row of this `tabular` array. It must be in `\def\listheadings` or in `\def\xlistheadings` in `g_orig_dest_tabular1_def.tex`. So how `\hline` could be added to the macro expansion that is used to create the first row of this `tabular` array?

Thank you :)

main.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\input{g_orig_dest_tabular1_def}

\begin{document}

\input{g_orig_dest_tabular1}

\end{document}
```

g_orig_dest_tabular1_def.tex:

```
\newcommand\connorigdestregionlist{ABC,DEF,GHI}

% hardline.
\def\hardline{\hline}

% listheadings.
\def\listheadings{%
\expandafter\xlistheadings\connorigdestregionlist,\relax,}

% xlistheadings.
\def\xlistheadings#1,{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\expandafter\\
\else
&\textbf{#1}%
\expandafter\xlistheadings
\fi}

% listbody.
\def\listbody{%
\expandafter\xlistbody\connorigdestregionlist,\relax,}

% xlistbody.
\def\xlistbody#1,{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\else
\textbf{#1}%
\gdef\thisrow{#1}%
\expandafter\xlistdata\connorigdestregionlist,\relax,%
\expandafter\hardline
\expandafter\xlistbody
\fi}

% xlistdata.
\def\xlistdata#1,{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\expandafter\\
\else
&\csname CONNorig\thisrow dest#1\endcsname
\expandafter\xlistdata
\fi}

% preamble.
\def\preamble{\expandafter\xpreamble\connorigdestregionlist,\relax,}
\def\xpreamble#1,{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\else
c%
\expandafter\xpreamble
\fi}

% tablestart.
\def\tablestart{%
\edef\temp{\noexpand\begin{tabular}{c\preamble}\noexpand\hline}%
    \temp}
```

g_orig_dest_tabular1.tex:

```
\input{g_orig_dest_conn_def}

\tiny
\begin{table}
    \scalebox{0.6}{
    \tablestart
    \listheadings
    \listbody
    \end{tabular}
    } % end scalebox
    \caption{Caption goes here.}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item number one. 
        \item Item number two.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{table}
\normalsize
```

g_orig_dest_conn_def.tex:

```
\def\CONNorigABCdestABC{ NA }
\def\CONNorigABCdestDEF{ from ABC to DEF }
\def\CONNorigABCdestGHI{ from ABC to GHI }

\def\CONNorigDEFdestABC{ from DEF to ABC }
\def\CONNorigDEFdestDEF{ NA }
\def\CONNorigDEFdestGHI{ from DEF to GHI }

\def\CONNorigGHIdestABC{ from GHI to ABC }
\def\CONNorigGHIdestDEF{ from GHI to DEF }
\def\CONNorigGHIdestGHI{ NA }
```

Comment: maybe I don't understand, but don't you just want `\hline` after the call to `\listheadings` as in the original answer?

Comment: Does the following definition do the job: `\def\xlistheadings#1,{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\expandafter\\\hline
\else
&\textbf{#1}%
\expandafter\xlistheadings
\fi}`

Comment: @David Carlisle: Yes, but then as I have to create several different `tabular` arrays using slightly modified versions of this code, I thought that it would be easier to use, modify and maintain if all the code to create a `tabular` array of this kind was created by using only `\tablestart \listheadings \listbody`.

Comment: @Marco Daniel: It is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: well if all your arrays need a line after the heading just add `\hline` as the last thing in the definition of `\listheadings`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a hline you can change the command `\xlistheadings` or `\listheadings`

The modification of `\xlistheadings`:

```
\def\xlistheadings#1,{%
 \ifx\relax#1%
  \expandafter\\\hline
 \else &\textbf{#1}%
 \expandafter\xlistheadings 
\fi}
```

The modification of `\listheadings`

```
\def\listheadings{%
\expandafter\xlistheadings\connorigdestregionlist,\relax,\hline}
```

Take your preferred way.