# How to use \hline in \edef macro to generate table

Tags: tables, macros

does someone know how to add `\hline` to a macro which is used to generate a table?

My MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{appdocs}
\setcounter{appdocs}{1}
\renewcommand{\theappdocs}{AD\arabic{appdocs}}
\newcommand{\appdocsCnt}[1]{%
  \theappdocs% Print counter
  \refstepcounter{appdocs}\label{#1}}% Mark with label

\newcommand{\applicabledocumententries}{}
\newcommand{\applicabledocument}[3]{%
\protected@xdef\applicabledocumententries{\applicabledocumententries \protect\appdocsCnt{#1} & #2 & #3 \protect\\}}

\newcommand{\applicabledocumentstable}{%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm}|X|p{4cm}}%9.8
    \hline
    {\bfseries Ref.} & {\bfseries Title} & {\bfseries Reference and Issue} \\\hline
    \applicabledocumententries
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\applicabledocument{ad:1}{myTexta}{someDate}
\applicabledocument{ad:2}{myTextb}{anotherDate}
\applicabledocument{ad:3}{myTextc}{randomDate}
\applicabledocumentstable

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

But I would like to have `\hline` after each entry of the list. [How to add \hline to macro expansion?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52649/how-to-add-hline-to-macro-expansion) might go into the correct direction, but I am not able to apply this to my example.

Comment: Doesn't `\protect\hline` work (as you have done, e.g., with `\\protect\\ `)? Please note, the example should show the problem. I cannot see any problem with any of the `\hline` in your example. I even cannot find a `\edef` (only a `\xdef`).

Comment: @Schweinebacke `\xdef` is equivalent to `\global\edef`. And `\protect\hline` does not work, it throws a `! Misplaced \noalign` error

Comment: I know the definition of `\xdef`. But you do not ask for a problem with `\xdef`. If you have a problem with `\xdef` you should ask for `\xdef`. If you title for `\edef` your example should use `\edef`. If you have a problem with adding `\hline` to the argument of a `\xdef` your example should show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\DeclareRobustCommand` to define a robust `\hline` or (as shown in the example) a tabular line end with `\hline`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}% Don't use \RequirePackage in document preamble after \documentclass

\makeatletter
\newcounter{appdocs}
\setcounter{appdocs}{1}
\renewcommand{\theappdocs}{AD\arabic{appdocs}}
\newcommand{\appdocsCnt}[1]{%
  \theappdocs% Print counter
  \refstepcounter{appdocs}\label{#1}}% Mark with label

\newcommand{\applicabledocumententries}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\tabularnewlinewithhline}{\\\hline}
\newcommand{\applicabledocument}[3]{%
\protected@xdef\applicabledocumententries{\applicabledocumententries \protect\appdocsCnt{#1} & #2 & #3 \tabularnewlinewithhline}}

\newcommand{\applicabledocumentstable}{%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm}|X|p{4cm}}%9.8
    \hline
    {\bfseries Ref.} & {\bfseries Title} & {\bfseries Reference and Issue} \\\hline
    \applicabledocumententries
\end{tabularx}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\applicabledocument{ad:1}{myTexta}{someDate}
\applicabledocument{ad:2}{myTextb}{anotherDate}
\applicabledocument{ad:3}{myTextc}{randomDate}
\applicabledocumentstable

\end{document}
```

As an alternative you can expand and eliminate the `\protect` before using `\applicabledocumententries`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{appdocs}
\setcounter{appdocs}{1}
\renewcommand{\theappdocs}{AD\arabic{appdocs}}
\newcommand{\appdocsCnt}[1]{%
  \theappdocs% Print counter
  \refstepcounter{appdocs}\label{#1}}% Mark with label

\newcommand{\applicabledocumententries}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\tabularnewlinewithhline}{\\\hline}
\newcommand{\applicabledocument}[3]{%
\protected@xdef\applicabledocumententries{\applicabledocumententries \protect\appdocsCnt{#1} & #2 & #3 \protect\\\protect\hline}}

\newcommand{\applicabledocumentstable}{%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm}|X|p{4cm}}%9.8
    \hline
    {\bfseries Ref.} & {\bfseries Title} & {\bfseries Reference and Issue}
  \\\hline
    \let\protect\noexpand
    \edef\applicabledocumententries{\applicabledocumententries}%
    \applicabledocumententries
\end{tabularx}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\applicabledocument{ad:1}{myTexta}{someDate}
\applicabledocument{ad:2}{myTextb}{anotherDate}
\applicabledocument{ad:3}{myTextc}{randomDate}
\applicabledocumentstable

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand` works  like a charm too! Thanks for the help :) It shouldn't have any drawback to declare it robust? I think this is a pretty clean solution

Comment: @user2943030: No drawback with the shown usage of the command. BTW: You could declare `\appdocsCnt` robust too and then remove the `\protect` before its usage.

Answer (score 1):

Below I've inserted a macro `\trules` that is originally set to `\relax` (not expandable) as part of the `\applicabledocumententries` construction. `\trules` is then set to `\hline` as part of `\applicabledocumentstable`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{appdocs}
\renewcommand{\theappdocs}{AD\arabic{appdocs}}
\newcommand{\appdocsCnt}[1]{%
  \mbox{}\refstepcounter{appdocs}\label{#1}% Mark with label
  \theappdocs% Print counter
}

\newcommand{\applicabledocumententries}{}
\let\trules\relax
\newcommand{\applicabledocument}[3]{%
  \protected@xdef\applicabledocumententries{%
    \applicabledocumententries \protect\appdocsCnt{#1} & #2 & #3 \protect\\ \trules}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\applicabledocumentstable}{%
  \let\trules\hline
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ p{2cm} | X | p{4cm} }
    \hline
    {\bfseries Ref.} & {\bfseries Title} & {\bfseries Reference and Issue} \\
    \hline
    \applicabledocumententries
  \end{tabularx}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\applicabledocument{ad:1}{myTexta}{someDate}
\applicabledocument{ad:2}{myTextb}{anotherDate}
\applicabledocument{ad:3}{myTextc}{randomDate}
\noindent
\applicabledocumentstable

\end{document}
```

The table looks far better without it though. Here is a version using [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs):

[image]

Comment: @user2943030: Note also that I've changed the order of your counter representation/usage. Your references would have been wrong otherwise.