# erraneous text in a LaTeX tabular array created using custom macros

Tags: tables, macros

I have a `tabular` array that is based on David Carlisle's answer to 
[Generating LaTeX tabular code during compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52472/generating-latex-tabular-code-during-compilation). I have modified the code so that columns and rows are defined in different `\newcommand` command definitions (practically lists). `\regionlist` contains brain regions `{ABC,DEF,GHI}` and `\contrastlist` contains 'contrasts' or activities `{SLEEP,RUN,SPEAK}`. These are defined in `g_loc_contrast_tabular_def.tex`. The data for the cells is defined in `g_loc_contrast_def.tex` using `\def` macro definitions, one for each data cell of the `tabular` array, excluding the top row and the left-most column.

So this particular array contains data on localized neural activity in different situations, the situations are on rows, brain regions on columns, and the data are defined by macros such as `\def\locBABCcontrastSLEEP{both ABCs during sleep}`. These definitions work fine.

I have added code to replace row headers with their descriptions that are defined in `g_loc_contrast_def.tex` using `\def` macros (`\contrastdescSLEEP`, `\contrastdescRUN`, `\contrastdescSPEAK`), but I have not been able to get the visual output right. On the leftmost column, I want "**deep sleep**" on the 1st data row (2nd row), "**running marathon**" on the 2nd data row (3rd row), and "**speaking**" (all with **bold**, without quotes), but I get **LEEP deep sleep SSLEEP**", "**UN running marathon RRUN**" and "**PEAK speaking SSPEAK**" (without quotes). The strings `RUN`, `SLEEP` and `SPEAK` are used in macro names, and when I finally found out a way to get the description in the array by using `\textbf{\newcommand\contrastdesc#1{\csname contrastdesc#1\endcsname}
\contrastdesc#1}%`, the first letter of the `#1` string, that holds the row-code (`SLEEP`, `RUN` or `SPEAK`), was moved to the right side of the description string together with complete row-code string. So I'm trying to find out what is wrong with my LaTeX code to get the output right.

I'm total beginner in LaTeX macros, so it might be just some basic mistake. I have tried to find a solution and to understand LaTeX macro system, but I think I understand still only a tiny bit of it.

The code compiles without problems by using `latexmk --pdf main.tex`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{filecontents}{g_loc_contrast_tabular_def}
\newcommand\regionlist{ABC,DEF,GHI}
\newcommand\contrastlist{SLEEP,RUN,SPEAK}

% listheadings.
\def\listheadings{%
\expandafter\xlistheadings\regionlist,\relax,}

% xlistheadings.
\def\xlistheadings#1,{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\expandafter\\\hline
\else
&\textbf{#1}%
\expandafter\xlistheadings
\fi}

% listbody.
\def\listbody{%
\expandafter\xlistbody\contrastlist,\relax,}

% xlistbody.
\def\xlistbody#1,{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\else
\textbf{\newcommand\contrastdesc#1{\csname contrastdesc#1\endcsname}
\contrastdesc#1}%
\gdef\thisrow{#1}
\expandafter\xlistdata\regionlist,\relax,%
\expandafter\hline
\expandafter\xlistbody
\fi}

% xlistdata.
\def\xlistdata#1,{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\expandafter\\
\else
&\csname locB#1contrast\thisrow\endcsname
\expandafter\xlistdata
\fi}

% preamble.
\def\preamble{\expandafter\xpreamble\regionlist,\relax,}
\def\xpreamble#1,{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\else
c%
\expandafter\xpreamble
\fi}

% tablestart.
\def\tablestart{%
\edef\temp{\noexpand\begin{tabular}{c\preamble}\noexpand\hline}%
    \temp}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{g_loc_contrast_def}
\def\locBABCcontrastSLEEP{ both ABCs during sleeping }
\def\locBABCcontrastRUN{ both ABCs during running }
\def\locBABCcontrastSPEAK{ both ABCs during speaking }

\def\locBDEFcontrastSLEEP{ both DEFs during sleeping }
\def\locBDEFcontrastRUN{ both DEFs during running } 
\def\locBDEFcontrastSPEAK{ both DEFs during speaking }

\def\locBGHIcontrastSLEEP{ both GHIs during sleeping }
\def\locBGHIcontrastRUN{ both GHIs during running } 
\def\locBGHIcontrastSPEAK{ both GHIs during speaking }

\def\contrastdescSLEEP{ deep sleep }
\def\contrastdescRUN{ running marathon }
\def\contrastdescSPEAK{ speaking }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{g_loc_contrast_tabular}
\tiny
\begin{table}
\scalebox{0.7}{
\tablestart
\listheadings
\listbody
\end{tabular}
} % end scalebox
\caption{Caption goes here.}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item number one. 
    \item Item number two.
\end{enumerate}
\end{table}
\normalsize
\end{filecontents}

\input{g_loc_contrast_tabular_def}
\input{g_loc_contrast_def}

\begin{document}

\input{g_loc_contrast_tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want

```
\def\xlistbody#1,{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\else
\textbf{\csname contrastdesc#1\endcsname}%
\gdef\thisrow{#1}
\expandafter\xlistdata\regionlist,\relax,%
\expandafter\hline
\expandafter\xlistbody
\fi}
```

[image]